# Java previous day convert to unix , yesterday format

Tags: java, unix, calendar, java-time

I have a Java program for yesterday's date and perform it on Unix. but my program is not working. The main point, every day I should to call date format `yyMMdd` and then I will use this date format to collect user logs. The output should be for example `193007`.

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Calendar;

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
Date yesterday = cal.getTime();
SimpleDateFormat formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd");
formattedYesterday = formattedDate.format(yesterday);
```

Comment: This is not JavaScript, this is Java.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what is not working, how your input looks like how the output currently looks like and if there are errors?

Comment: Thanks for wanting to add information to your question. Please use the edit link under the question for that. And please format code as such for readability.

Comment: You are using the old and troublesome way. The classes `Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated, no one should use them anymore. For your task use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: Your code looks like it should work, though. What incorrect result are you getting? PS I suppose you want 190730 when you say `yyMMdd`.

Comment: Output should be 190730 but faced issue ;
/Test1.java:11: error: ')' expected SimpleDateFormat formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern:"yyddMM"); ^ /Test1.java:11: error: not a statement SimpleDateFormat formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern:"yyddMM"); ^ /Test1.java:11: error: ';' expected SimpleDateFormat formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern:"yyddMM"); ^ 3 errors

Comment: I dont have experience, how I can use LocalDate and DateTimeFormatter in script ?

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: As an aside, pleeeeeeeeeeeeease use yyyymmdd.  I saw your example `193007` and assumed it was July, 1930, and I wondered, "Why is he working with data from 80 years ago?"

Answer (score 1):

Your Question is not clear, but it seems you want to determine today's date, go back a day to yesterday, and then generate a string representing that value in a particular format.

## Time zone

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter pseudo-zones such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
```

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

Subtract a day for yesterday.

```
LocalDate yesterday = today.minusDays( 1 ) ;
```

## Generating text

Generate a string in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format to represent this date value by calling [`LocalDate :: toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#toString()).

```
String output = yesterday.toString() ;
```

> 2019-07-30

Generate a string in your custom formatting pattern with [`DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern(java.lang.String,java.util.Locale)).

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuMMdd" ) ;
String output = yesterday.format( f ) ;
```

> 190730

## ISO 8601

I suggest you reconsider your choice of formats. The [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats were designed for a purpose, to be readily identifiable, easily parsed by machine, and easily read by humans across cultures. Your custom format is none of those things, and is likely to cause confusion/errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to get format like `yyddMM`.
You can change "yyMMdd" to "yyddMM".
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rgaE.png)